# Creating surjective holomorphic map from unit disc to $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to formulate a surjective holomorphic map from the unit disc ($\mathbb{D}$) to $\mathbb{C}$. I know that there exists $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$, which is a biholomorphism from the unit disc to the upper half plane.

I know that I can define $g(z) = z -i$ to shift the upper half plane down by 1 unit, then I can define $h(z) = z^2$ to square the result.

Then, $h \circ g \circ f$ is a holomorphic function $\mathbb{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. My question is: how does $h(z)$, (i.e. squaring the result of the shifted upper half plane), extend the image to the entire lower half plane?

[image]

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not seeing how $\mathbb{C}$ is hit in its entirety.

Comment: Think in terms of polar coordinates.

Answer (score 9):

You know that $h \colon ℂ → ℂ$ is surjective (by the fundamental theorem of algebra or using polar coordinates).

For any $w ∈ ℂ$, if $z^2 = w$, then $(-z)^2 = w$. Then $\Im (-z) = - \Im (z)$, so one of $z, -z$ is in $\mathbb H$, if not in $ℝ$. Therefore $h \colon \mathbb H - \mathrm i → ℂ$ is surjective as well.

And $g ∘ f \colon \mathbb D → \mathbb H-i$ is obviously surjective, as you said.

Comment: I don’t understand, what is the point of shifting H down by -i then?

Comment: Oh, I think to map onto when i = 0. If that’s right then shifting by .000000000000000001 i would also work.

Comment: I still don't understand why shifting H down by $-i$ will give $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @fieke_2000 $A = \{ z ∈ ℂ;~\Im z ≥ 0\} ⊆ \mathbb H - \mathrm i$, and $∀ w ∈ ℂ ~ ∃ z ∈ A \colon w = z^2$, so $ℂ ⊆ h(A)$, so $ℂ ⊆ h (\mathbb H - \mathrm i) = \operatorname{img} h$.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but here's for future viewers.

Shifting $\mathbb{H}$ down by 1 is performed in order to ensure each complex number $z=re^{i\theta}$ has a root within our domain.

Let $f$, $h$ be the functions you mentioned. Notice that $z=1$ doesn't have a square root in $f(\mathbb{D})=\mathbb{H}$, so $h\circ f$ isn't surjective.

Now let's "shift $\mathbb{H}$ down by $i$" with $g$.

Mark $g(\mathbb{H})="\mathbb{H}-i$"

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, $z$ has $2$ square roots in the Complex plane, $\sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$ and $\sqrt{r}e^{i(\theta/2+\pi)}$.

Because the difference between their angles with the real axis is $\pi$ we are guaranteed at least one of them (mark it as $z_1$) will be in $\mathbb{H}\cup\mathbb{R}$ (draw it down to see why). Now because $\mathbb{H}\cup\mathbb{R}$ is contained in $\mathbb{H}-i$ we know $z_1\in\mathbb{H}-i$.

We know $g\circ f$ is surjective from $\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{H}-i$ then there exists $z_2$ so that $g\circ f(z_2)=z_1$ and that $z_1^2=z$ so $h\circ g\circ f(z_2)=z$.

As this is true for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ we get $h\circ g\circ f$ is surjective.

Indeed we could have chosen a different "shift" of $\mathbb{H}$, so long as its a shift down in the imaginary axis.