# Non Existence of a proper holomorphic map from the unit disc onto the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

It is well known that there is no proper holomorphic map from complex plane onto disc by Liouville's theorem.Does there exist a proper holomorphic map $f$ from the unit disc onto the complex plane?I believe that such map does not exists but I'm unable to prove this.Please Help!

**Def**:A map $f:X \to Y$ is called a proper map if $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact in $X$ for every compact set $K$ in $Y$.

Comment: Any holomorphic map from the unit disk to the complex plane is automatically proper, so I think you can remove the properness assumption. The real question is whether there is a holomorphic map from the unit disk ONTO the complex plane.

Comment: @AlexFok This is not true.  For example, the map described in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036380/creating-surjective-holomorphic-map-from-unit-disc-to-mathbbc) is not proper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such map.  For convenience, I will use the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$ instead of the unit disk.

Suppose $f\colon \mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a proper holomorphic map.

Note first that, for each sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $\mathbb{H}$ that converges to a point $p$ on the real axis, the image sequence $\{f(z_n)\}$ must must converge to $\infty$ on the Riemann sphere.  To prove this, observe that if $\overline{D}_R$ is the closed disk of radius $R$ in $\mathbb{C}$ centered at the origin, then $\overline{D}_R$ is compact, and hence $f^{-1}(\overline{D}_R)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{H}$.  Then $\mathbb{C}-f^{-1}(\overline{D}_R)$ is an open neighborhood of $p$, so $z_n$ lies in the complement of $f^{-1}(\overline{D}_R)$ for all but finitely many $n$.  This holds for all $R>0$, which proves the claim.

Now, since $f$ is a nonzero holomorphic function, the zeroes of $f$ form a discrete subset of $\mathbb{H}$.  Since $f$ is proper, the set of zeroes must be compact, and therefore there are only finitely many zeroes.  Let $D$ be any open disk centered on the real axis that does not contain any zeroes of $f$, and consider the holomorphic function $g(z) = 1/f(z)$ on $D\cap\mathbb{H}$.

Now, $g$ has the property that $g(z_n) \to 0$ for any sequence $z_n \in D\cap\mathbb{H}$ converging to a point on the real axis. Thus $g$ extends continuously to $D\cap\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ by setting $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in D\cap\mathbb{R}$.  By the [Schwarz reflection principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchwarzReflectionPrinciple.html), $g$ now extends to a holomorphic function on all of $D$, which is nonsense since $g$ is zero on $D\cap\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry - why does properness imply $f(z_n)\to \infty$ for $Im(z_n)\to 0$?

Comment: @Neal For a proper map, the image of any sequence that escapes to infinity must escape to infinity.  See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map).  In this case, the argument would be that the preimage of the closed disk of radius $R$ in the complex plane must be a compact subset of $\mathbb{H}$, and therefore contains only finitely many $z_n$.

Comment: In this case, would it be more precise to say the image of any sequence with no convergent subsequence must be a sequence with no convergent subsequence? For instance, $1 + i/n$ doesn't escape to infinity as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @Neal Here "escape to infinity" is being used in the technical sense -- a sequence $\{x_n\}$ "escapes to infinity" in a topological space $X$ if, for every compact subset $K$ of $X$, the sequence has only finitely many terms in $K$.  Thus the sequence $\{1+i/n\}$ *does* escape to infinity in $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: @Neal I've added an argument about this to clarify my answer.

Comment: Ah, okay. I either had forgotten or hadn't seen it used in that sense before. Thank you -- totally cleared it up!