# Conformal maps and möbius transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Is it possible to find a möbius transformation mapping $\mathbb{C}$ to the unit disc $D(0,1)$

my attempt:

I think that since $\mathbb{C}$ isn't bounded by any circlines but the unit disc is bounded by a circle centre $0$ radius $1$ then we can't find such a composition of mobius transformations to do so.

Is this correct, any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No holomorphic function can map the complex plane to a bounded open set. See
[Liouville's theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Liouville%27s_Theorem_(complex_analysis)#:%7E:text=In%20complex%20analysis%2C%20Liouville%27s%20Theorem,Theorem%20is%20a%20stronger%20result).

Comment: Excuse me and is it possible to find a surjective mapping holomorphic from D to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, scale your points as $r \mapsto \tan(r \cdot \pi)$. But this is not a Mobius transformation.

Comment: does this work too? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036380/creating-surjective-holomorphic-map-from-unit-disc-to-mathbbc

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Mobius transformations send generalized circles to generalized circles. A generalized circle is a cirlce or a line. If there was a Mobius transformation sending $\mathbb{C}$ to the disk, then its inverse would also be a Mobius transformation and would send the unit circle to some other generalized circle, exactly as you say. Since Mobius transformations are continuous the unit circle will be mapped on one of the sides of the generalized circle.